# Given $a_0=1$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}$, for primes $p\le 13$ prove there are infinitely many terms divisible by $p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

I have been able to solve the cases for $p=2$ and $3$. For $p\ge 5$, I suspect that a general formula giving an infinite sequence of $k$ such that $p|a_k$ is not possible; however I may be wrong.

The sequence does not appear on OEIS.

Edit: As suggested below, here I'll repeat the question in the description:

There is a sequence of integers $\{a_n\}$ where $n\ge 0$, which satisfies $a_0=1$ and the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor}$. For every prime $p$ where $p\le 13$, prove that there exist infinitely many $k$ such that $p|a_k$.

Edit: As suggested by a comment, I’ll add some details/context: 
This is a problem in one of my exercises, in a high-school-level maths olympic training. I don’t know anything about the author/country/source etc.

Here are my solutions for $p=2$ and $3$:

For $p=2$, suppose that (for contradiction) for every $k\ge N$, $2\nmid a_k$. Then consider $a_{3k}=a_{3k-1}+a_k$. As both terms on the right side are odd, the left side must be even. Contradiction.

For $p=3$ the problem is very obvious, since $a_{3k+2}=a_{3k-1}+3a_k$, and $a_2$ is $3$, which gives $\forall k\ 3|k\implies 3|a_k$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit your question in such a way that understanding it does not depend upon reading its title.

Comment: What do you mean by "understanding it does not depend upon reading its title"?

Comment: The original version of your question could not be understood by someone who had not read its title.

Comment: Please give more context around the question, as shown in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question - since context matters. The cases $p=2$ and $p=3$ are done?! Please share with us the ideas, a potential answerer will have an easier start, extract already known computation and thoughts, and type a pointed, more compact answer covering new facts only. Other interesting details would be the level of the problem, the source, country, contest, author, link(s) - and so on, if known / if applicable. It is the way it works, note there is already a pending close

Answer (score 1):

Sequence $\{a_n\}$ is in OEIS, see [A005704](http://oeis.org/A005704).

Proof: $a_1=2$, $a_2=3$, $a_3=5$, $a_4=7$, $a_{11}=33=3*11$, $a_{20}=117=9*13$.

If $a_m$ is divisible by prime $p$, then $a_{3m+2}\equiv{a_{3m+1}}\equiv{a_{3m}}\equiv{a_{3m-1}}\mod p$. Suppose $a_{3m-1}\equiv{r}\mod p$. Thus $a_{9m-3}\equiv{a_{9m-4}+a_{3m-1}}\equiv{a_{9m-4}+r}\mod p$, $a_{9m-2}\equiv{a_{9m-3}+a_{3m-1}}\equiv{a_{9m-4}+2r}\mod p$, ..., $a_{9m+8}\equiv{a_{9m+7}+a_{3m+2}}\equiv{a_{9m-4}+12r}\mod p$.

If $r=0$, then $a_{3m-1}$ is divisible by $p$, otherwise there exists $k\in\{9m-4,9m-3,9m-2,...,9m+8\}$ such that $a_k$ is divisible by $p$, where prime $p\le 13$.